# How to Update a prop array after deleting an element using axios with server components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I am using TypeScript with Nextjs and axios for http requests.
I need to create some optimistic UI, so when I delete a record, the rest of records should remain.

What I done so far.

1. I created a fetcher so I can drag the axios all over my application... In the fetcher I created two methods. One for getting all the quotes, and second to delete individual quotes. In the second one, I also executed the first function because I want to render the remaining records.

```
import axios from "axios";


export const API_Endpoint = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/'
});


//get all the quotes
export const getAllQuotes = async () => {
    const response = await API_Endpoint.get('get-quotes');
    return response.data;
};


//delete the quotes and execute the getAllQuotes to return the remaining quotes
export const deleteQuoteById = async (quoteId: string) => {
    await API_Endpoint.delete(`delete-quote?id=${quoteId}`);
    const allRemainingQuotes = await getAllQuotes();
    return allRemainingQuotes;
}
```

2. In the main page, which is a server component (async), I set up the promises needed and await all the variables like nextjs recommend (parallel), than I pass the variable to the Quotes component.

```
const AdminDahsboard = async () => {
  //Get quotes 
  const AllClientQuotes: Promise<IQuote[]> = getAllQuotes();

  //Get here the remaining records needed
  const [allQuotes] = await Promise.all([AllClientQuotes]);

  return (
    <section>
      <BlackBanner title='Admin manage clients' subtitle='Manage clients, delete/mark as complete quotes, delete/accept reviews'/>

      {/* //All client quotes */}
      <Quotes quotes={allQuotes} 
        title='All client quotes' 
        subtitle='You can delete, mark as completed/paid, or assign a driver..'/>


    </section>
  )
}
```

3. The creation of the Quotes component, which is a CLIENT COMPONENT. I pass the quotes array, and create a function to map over the array and render the records. In the function I setup a button with the delete function that will return that remaining array from POINT 1.

```
  const handleDeleteQuoteById = async (quoteId: string): Promise<IQuote[]> => {
    //return the remaining quotes in the response
    const response = await deleteQuoteById(quoteId);
    return response;
  };
```

The function that maps over the array:

```
  const mapOverQUotes = (quotesArray: IQuote[]) => quotesArray.map(quote => (
    <div key={quote.id} 
    className="flex justify-between p-3 my-3 bg-gray-100">

      <div className="">
        <p>{ quote.nameClient }</p>
        <a href={`tel:${quote.phoneNumber}`}>{quote.phoneNumber}</a><br />
        <a href={`mailto:${quote.clientEmail}`}>{quote.clientEmail}</a>
      </div>

      {/* Div with the quotes and the delete button */}
      <div>
        <p className="pl-3">Actions</p>
        <div className="flex">
          <button className="bg-transparent m-1 p-3" 
          onClick={() => handleDeleteQuoteById(quote.id)}>
            <MdDelete size={25} color="red"/>
          </button>

          <Link href={`/individual-quote/${quote.id}`}
            className="bg-transparent m-1 p-3" >
            <CiSettings size={25} color="black"/>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  ));
```

And than, returned the original component with map function inside

```
 return (
    <section className="py-12">
      <MaxWidthLayout>
        <BasicMainTitle black>{ title }</BasicMainTitle>
        <p className="my-3">{ subtitle }</p>

        {
          mapOverQUotes(quotes)
        }

      </MaxWidthLayout>
    </section>
  )
}
```

**What I tried**
a. Because the admin page is a server component, and the quotes page needs to be client(need interactivity), I also tried to make the admin page client. But there was an infinite loop...

b. I also tried to use SWR, but there was again infinite loop.

What should I do?

Comment: UPDATE. In the component section, i created another state which I used to map over instead to map over the PROP passed. And in the delete individual quote, I set the new state of quotes as the remaining array minus the one that has been deleted. I don't know if is a good idea, but it was a work around that worked